# How Can I filter the data based on textbox values that inside the table data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
                $("#srch").on("keyup", function() {
                            var value = $(this).val();
                        
                            $("#Filtertable tr").each(function(index) {
                                if (index !== 0) {
                        
                                    $row = $(this);
                        
                                    var id = $row.find("td:nth(1)").val();
                        
                                    if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                                        $row.hide();
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $row.show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                
        
        
        
        
        
    <table id="Filtertable" style="width: 40%; border: 1px solid black;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" Value=" Hi Tom"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" Value=" Hi Jerry"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox"> </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" Value=" Happy Morning"> </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>



This is my code, Can someone explain How to get the value of textbox inside the td
```

How can I filter the data after adding some extra rows, Tried Many examples but nothing worked so far, Please Help.
Is there any alternative Way available to do this filter???
Nothing worked so far since I dont know How to get it done!
Any solution without using JQuery is also appriciated..

Comment: Please include all relevant code and what you have tried. Your js don't really show any attempt.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have edited the code, Can you please share your idea to how its should done

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen The Solution is working fine, but case sensitive it seems . Thank you so much

Comment: Updated the demo, now it ignores case sensitive

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen perfectly working!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 problems.

To get the value in a `<td>` you have to use `.text()`, or you can add `input` in the selector.

```
  var id = $row.find("td:nth(1) input").val();

  if (id.indexOf(value) == -1) {
    $row.hide();
  } else {
    $row.show();
  }
```

Also it has to be `id.indexOf(value) == -1`

**Demo**

```js
$("#srch").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  $("#Filtertable tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {

      $row = $(this);

      var id = $row.find("td:nth(1) input").val().toLowerCase();

      if (id.indexOf(value) == -1) {
        $row.hide();
      } else {
        $row.show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Filtertable" style="width: 40%; border: 1px solid black;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"> </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" Value=" Hi Tom"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"> </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" Value=" Hi Jerry"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"> </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" Value=" Happy Morning"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input id="srch" />
```